# Java - counting the occurrences of a character in a random generator method using a separate method

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of stars that were printed last time the print() method was used.

I'm confused on how to take the value of starsInLastPrint variable into the starsInLastPrint() method. My understanding is that this isn't possible. I assume there are plenty of things wrong with my current code that isn't helping. Below is my current state as I am stuck.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NightSky {

private double density;
private int width;
private int height;
private int starsInLastPrint;

public NightSky(double density) {
    width = 20;
    height = 10;
    this.density = density;
}

public NightSky(int width, int height) {
    density = 0.1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}

public NightSky(double density, int width, int height) {
    this.density = density;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void printLine() {
    Random starPlacement = new Random();
    String[] stars = new String[(this.width)];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        double random = starPlacement.nextDouble();
        if (random <= this.density) {
            stars[i] = "*";
            this.starsInLastPrint++;
        } else {
            stars[i] = " ";
        }
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (j < stars.length) {
        System.out.print(stars[j]);
        j++;

    }
    System.out.println("");

}

public void print() {

    NightSky nightSky = new NightSky(this.density, this.width, this.height);

    this.starsInLastPrint = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < this.height) {
        nightSky.printLine();
        i++;
    }

}

public int starsInLastPrint() {

    return this.starsInLastPrint;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Though, you don't need to instantiate another NightSky object inside the print method. You can just do the following,

```
public void print() {
    this.starsInLastPrint = 0;
    int i=0;
    while (i < this.height) {
        printLine();
        i++;
    }

}
```

So, everytime you call print, it will update the stars count for that print method call. Here is the whole code,

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NightSky {

private double density;
private int width;
private int height;
private int starsInLastPrint;

public static void main(String[] args){

    NightSky sky = new NightSky(5,5);
    sky.print();
    System.out.println(sky.starsInLastPrint());

    sky.print();
    System.out.println(sky.starsInLastPrint());
}


public NightSky(double density) {
    width = 20;
    height = 10;
    this.density = density;
}

public NightSky(int width, int height) {
    density = 0.1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}

public NightSky(double density, int width, int height) {
    this.density = density;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void printLine() {
    Random starPlacement = new Random();
    String[] stars = new String[(this.width)];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        double random = starPlacement.nextDouble();
        if (random <= this.density) {
            stars[i] = "*";
            this.starsInLastPrint++;
        } else {
            stars[i] = " ";
        }
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (j < stars.length) {
        System.out.print(stars[j]);
        j++;

    }
    System.out.println("");

}

public void print() {
    this.starsInLastPrint = 0;
    int i=0;
    while (i < this.height) {
        printLine();
        i++;
    }

}

public int starsInLastPrint() {

    return this.starsInLastPrint;

}

}
```

Sample run of the above code:

```
*   *
  *  

  *  
4





0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense.